# findcontrol not able to find a literal control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, findcontrol

I have  aspx page something like this:

```
<panel><Div><div><asp:Literal ID="ShoppingCart1" runat="server" /></div></div></panel>
```

And aspx.cs page like this :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { DisplayShoppingCartItems();}
void DisplayShoppingCartItems()
    {Literal shoppingCart1 = FindControl("ShoppingCart1") as Literal;}
```

I am not able to find this literal like this.Always getting it as null

Comment: What it is "around" the `<panel>` in the aspx.page file? In many cases you should be able to just use `ShoppingCart1` directly in your code, instead of first finding it using `FindControl`. If that doesn't work, then you need to show us more of the markup from the aspx file.

Comment: Using the id directly doesnt seem to work

Comment: ...then you need to show us more of the markup from the aspx file.

Comment: @user1429080 : The aspx page has divs,then this panel

Comment: Its actually <div><panel><div><div><literal></div></div></panel></div>